# error MSB4044: The "CheckRuntimeLibrary" task was not given a value for the required parameter "RuntimeLibrary"

Tags: c++

I tried to use  a C++ code for converting  `mnist` dataset  into `lmdb` format. I installed all the needed packages, but when I ran the code I got this error:

> Error MSB4044: The "CheckRuntimeLibrary" task was not given a value for the required parameter "RuntimeLibrary".   c:\Users\mohamed-witti-adou\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Project2\packages\gflags.2.1.1.2\build\native\gflags.targets

I am new to C++ and VS coding, I would like some help to overcome this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As noone else has answered and I found this question when Googling my error text: The problem in my case was that I was building a completely empty Visual Studio project that I had copied and modified for a new project. When I added a source file to the project the error went away.